# Scroll Magic Parallax Problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax, scrollmagic

I'm just trying to create a basic 2 layer parallax effect with scrollmagic on my index page that has a gigantic image and content below it. I looked the the documentation and source code several times but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know what I'm missing:

html:

```
<div class="row zero-padding parallaxParent" id="parallax1">
  <div class="col-xs-12 zero-padding index--background" style="background-image: url('{{ backgroundimage.picture.url }}')">
    <h1>MACRO FOODS</h1>
    <h2>Healthy made easy</h2>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row zero-padding">
  <div class="col-xs-12 index--title">
    <p> What is Macro Foods?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row zero-padding index--blockwrap">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
    <p class="index--body">{{ whatismacrofoods.text }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <img class="index--image" src="{{ imagesindex1.picture.url }}">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<!--Custom-->
<script src="{% static 'scripts/main.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'scripts/parallax.js' %}"></script>
```

css:

```
.parallaxParent {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parrallaxParent > * {
  height: 200%;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
}
```

parallax.js:

```
//Parallax Scrollmagic
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({globalSceneOptions: {triggerHook: "onEnter", duration: "200%"}});

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#parallax1", duration: "120%"})
.setTween("#parallax1 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone})
.addIndicators()
.addTo(controller);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#parallax2"})
.setTween("#parallax2 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone})
.addIndicators()
.addTo(controller);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#parallax3"})
.setTween("#parallax3 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone})
.addIndicators()
.addTo(controller);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT after edit of original post:

I don't see `TweenMax.js` and `animation.gsap.js` referenced in your code - or is that somehow included in the other scripts?

---

Another addition after second comment:

`TweenMax.js` can be referenced like this

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

`animation.gsap.js` like this:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
```

but you should also find it in the "plugins" folder of your "scrollmagic" folder.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working on my site even when I put in that duration in the triggerElement still for some reason.

I also copied pretty much line for line on the example, but it doesn't seem to click.

http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/parallax_sections.html

Comment: Nope, I had a feeling that may be the problem. I'm really new to all of this and I'm not sure exactly how the jquery plugins work/what do I include. I went to scroll magic site and copied/pasted the two lines on the front page. Is there like a CDN I can import for Tweenmax/animation? do I download it? If I download, which folder to I reference it from and how do I know which file I'm looking for if they give me a whole zip folder?